# JAXB extend generated code with extended object factory - explicit casts good?

Tags: java, types, interface, casting, jaxb

I've got some JAXB generated beans which are in an hierarchical structure, e.g. one bean holds a list of other beans. Now I want to extend some child element and also the parent element holding the  extended children.

My `ParentEx` implements some other interface `IParent` which is expected to return an `Collection<IChild>`. My `ChildEx` implements `IChild`. Can I return a `(Collection<IChild>)super.getChild()` when `super.getChild()` returns `List<Child>`? Or is there a nicer way of doing this?

- `Child` and `Parent` are JAXB generated beans
- `ChildEx` and `ParentEx` are my own beans for mapping the JAXB beans to the given interfaces. Both beans override the `ObjectFactory`
- `IChild` and `IParent` are the interfaces needed from some other library

**Edit:** Eclipse doesn't even let my cast from `List<Child>` to `List<ChildEx>` so I have to add some ugly intermediary wildcard cast `(List<ChildEx>)(List<?>)super.getChild()`

Comment: Why would you need to do this? `List<Child>` "is a" `Collection<Child>` in any case. Unless I am missing the obvious, the `IParent` interface is fully satisfied by any `IChild` implementation, too?

Comment: Thanks, but no, the `Parent` has the method `List<Child> getChild()` and the `IParent` says it needs to return a `Collection<IChild>`. Therefore I will have to do an exlicit cast in my `ParentEx`. I don't want to modify the autogenerated beans, hence the only way to get autogenerated beans fitted for the `IParent` interface is to write a own `ParentEx implements IParent`

Comment: Does the solution with new ArrayList work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
return new ArrayList<IChild>( childExList );
```

or (not pretty but avoids wildcard cast):

```
return Arrays.asList( childExList.toArray(new IChild[]{}) );
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java it's not type safe to cast `Generic<Type>` to `Generic<SuperType>` which is what you are trying to do by casting `List<Child>` to `Collection<IChild>`. Imagine a `List<Integer>` being cast to `List<Object>`, that would allow you to put anything into the list, not just `Integer` or subtypes.

It is safe to cast `Generic<Type>` to `GenericSuperType<Type>` as user268396 points out in the comment.

You are going to need to copy the `List<Child>` into some new collection e.g.

```
List<Child> sourceList = ...
List<IChild> targetList = new ArrayList<IChild>();
Collections.copy(targetList, sourceList);
```

You can then return `targetList` which can be implicitly cast to `Collection<IChild>`